# What is the format for specifying the path of multiple feature files in CucumberOptions?

Tags: selenium, cucumber, bdd, cucumber-java

What is the format for specifying the path of multiple feature files in CucumberOptions?
Here in below code I need to specify path to more than one feature files

```
@CucumberOptions(
        features="C:\\Users\\Chan\\eclipse-workspace\\BDDCucumber\\src\\test\\resources\\sample.feature",
        glue= {"com.bdd.stepdefinition"},
        tags={"@UATTesting"},
        plugin= {"pretty","html:target/site/cucumber-pretty","json:target/cucumber.json"},
        monochrome=true
        )
```

public class TestRunner{
        private TestNGCucumberRunner testNGCucumberRunner;

Comment: features={"path to feature1","path to feature2"}

Comment: I have created FeatureFiles folder directly inside the project in eclipse and inside the FeatureFiles folder I have kept 2 feature files. And I want to run both the features in the same execution. @Grasshopper